# pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 61] Connection refused

Tags: python, anaconda, pymongo

I am learning to use pymongo, but I get stuck on the intro code from this website https://realpython.com/introduction-to-mongodb-and-python/#sql-vs-nosql:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.pymongo_test

posts = db.posts
post_data = {'title': 'Python and MongoDB'}
result = posts.insert_one(post_data)
```

After the last line, I get the error in the header. I have no experience with databases, so I have no idea where to start debugging this.

I am using Python 3.7.3, pymongo 3.7.2 and mongodb 4.0.3 on a Mac OS X.

Comment: `brew tap mongodb/brew` followed by `brew install mongodb-community@6.0` if you're using the most recent version. 
Check the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out - I thought that just installing the mongodb package on Anaconda was enough, but I had to install MongoDB properly using brew.